# Movie about a family replaced by clones

Tags: story-identification, movie, clones

There's a film I remember seeing as a kid that I thought was really scary. I've never found out what it was. Can anyone help naming it?

This was on TV in the UK approx 20–25 years ago. It was about a family (mother, father, children) that discovered they had clones. I remember towards the end the clones and the real family fought. The family survived and as they were being put in the ambulance unconscious  the doors were shut and the medical staff were revealed to be more clones. Also I'm almost certain this was not an Outer Limits or Twighlight Zone episode, as this was a film.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [Stepford Wives](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073747/) or [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077745/).

More like Body Snatchers, really, as Stepford Wives is robots.

And Body Snatchers was hitting TV in the mid 80's and late 80's, from it's 1978 theatrical release. Check the above links to IMDB and see if the cast photos ring any bells.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the episode "The Two Faces Of Evil" from the UK anthology series "Hammer House of Horror".

- first aired 1980
- british production
- family on vacation
- doppelgangers
- ambulance in the end

Comment: Full episode [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3gi8vy) on Vimeo